# image not displaying in php whle accessing images in directory

Tags: php, html

I am learning programming in php, Recently i used php file to access directory to display images in the webpage but coudnot do so. I am pasting the source code and page source that appears in chrome. As checked, the path appears to be right and only thing visible in browser is image thumbnail

PHP CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Displaying Images within a directory</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$dir = $root.'/house';
$opdir = opendir($dir);
if($opdir){
    $images = array();
    while(false !== ($file = readdir($opdir)))//keep on looping till you do not find any file in directory. analogous to fgets.!== means not identical and will be false when they are not equal or not of same type
    {
    if($file != '.' && $file!= '..');//they are directory files in windows pc so we have to skip them
    {
        array_push($images, $file);
    }
}
}
sort($images);
foreach ($images as $key) {
    $imagename = 'house/'.$key;
    print "<p><img src='".$imagename."'></p>\r\n";
}
?>
</body>
</html>







**HTML SOURCE AS SEEN IN BROWSER**

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Displaying Images within a directory</title>
</head>
<body>
<p><img src='house/.'></p>
<p><img src='house/..'></p>
<p><img src='house/bayview_1.jpg'></p>
<p><img src='house/bayview_2.jpg'></p>
<p><img src='house/mallard_1.jpg'></p>
<p><img src='house/moduler_1.jpg'></p>
<p><img src='house/townhome_1.jpg'></p>
<p><img src='house/white_house.jpg'></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly, what do you expect as opposed to what you get?

Comment: First check in your browsers development console, in the network tab, what result your browser gets back as a request to the images. You can see the same in the access and error log file of your http server. I could be that the access is denied due to file system permissions. That is something you have to check, since only you have access to your system. We cannot really help much here.

Comment: instead of `$imagename = 'house/'.$key;` try `$imagename = '/house/'.$key;`. That might help, or not...

Comment: @jeroen Sir, I expect to get images being displayed in the browser, but I am not getting any. I am just getting those small thumbnails . Plus whenever i click on the source of the image, it shows that directory cannot be accessed.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware this worked, thanks a ton :)

Comment: You're welcome. The reason it works is because it now assumes the `house` directory follows directly after the domain, like this: `http://domain.com/house`, and not somewhere else like: `http://domain.com/test/house`, if your test script was in this `test` directory.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware  i am using XAMPP, and the house directory was in the root folder only. the test script was in a separate directory in the root only. o.O